# How to protect routes using middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, middleware

How can i make a nextjs 13 middleware to protect routes if user is not authenticated.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req) {
    let verify = req.cookies.get('loggedin');

    if (!verify) {
        return NextResponse.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
    }

    return NextRequest.next();
}
```